# Restrict access to files in folders with .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to restrict access to all files in a folder.

I have to check if the user is authenticated and some other verifications. So I have to check it in a PHP file.

But I think I have to pass by a .htaccess file, that should check if the user want to access to a file in some specifics folder and then redirect to my "filehandler.php" file.

I want to restrict access to all files in a "documents/private/" folder and its subfolders.
Then I tried this (.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(private/|dummy)\/.*$
RewriteRule !^((.*.html)|(.*\/))$ filehandler.php
```

But it doesn't redirect to the "filehandler.php" file.

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance

PS: I found lots of explanations about it, but as I don't know the syntax at all, I didn't succeed to make what I want to do.